# When I run gem install *some gem name* where does it install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gemfile

As the question states - where does the gem install?

Is it installing within the app directory that I'm working in (i.e. user/sites/sample_app)? Or is it being installed on my computer? If the latter where exactly?

Thanks!

Comment: That depend on how and where you installed Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

gem install process

first download gem and save desktop
1.next step open command prompt and set location that means c:/desktop> gem install  --local "gemname"
2.next step com to rails consoler and type $bundle install --local.
3. type the gem name on gem list

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions:

Where do you install your ruby?

Did you use RVM or rbenv?

Now I will explain your question using my situation as an example.

I use RVM to manage rubies on my mac os.

now the ruby install in path

```
/Users/pin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1
```

and these will be a gems directory under .rvm path. In this directory,

```
/Users/pin/.rvm/gems
```

there are many gems group, I have a group named

```
ruby-2.1.1@global
```

which is used by the default ruby version.

This is a directory and there will be a gems directory under it.

```
/Users/pin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems
```

In this directory, you will find all of the gems you installed using cmd

```
bundle install
```

If you don't use ruby version management tools like rvm or rbenv, you may find the gems

around your ruby path. If you still can't find them, you can post the details of how you

install the rubies and other system configs, so that we can discuss here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rvm then its get installed in

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@global/ or /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-version/
```

If you are using specific gemset for gems then

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@gemset_name/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Gems**

If you use [`gem install x`](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#installing-gems), you're adding the `gem` to the local ruby version on your system. This is a system-wide installation, and will be stored in your `rubylib/ruby/gems` dir:

> The install command downloads and installs the gem and any necessary
>   dependencies then builds documentation for the installed gems.

---

[**Bundler**](http://bundler.io/v1.6/rationale.html)

Using the `bundle install` command (when you have a `Gemfile` & use [`bundler`](http://bundler.io/v1.6/rationale.html)), you basically tell `bundler` to install the gems relative to your specific applicaiton:

> Bundler makes sure that Ruby can find all of the gems in the Gemfile
>   (and all of their dependencies). If your app is a Rails 3 app, your
>   default application already has the code necessary to invoke bundler.
>   If it is a Rails 2.3 app, please see Setting up Bundler in Rails 2.3.

For example, if you have a `Rails 3.2` app, and a `Rails 4.1` app on your system, using `bundler` allows you to instal the dependencies (gems) for each app independently

If you use `gem install x`, it will install the gem for *all*  applications, and should only be used for things like [`rmagick`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick) and the database connection gems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know where gem is installed use `gem which *gem_name*` e.g.:

```
gem which rails
```

If you installed your gems with bundle install use `bundle show *gem name*` e.g.:

```
bundle show rails
```